# Eclipse: how to show SVG with SWT or free open source SVG Viewer plugin?

Tags: eclipse, open-source, swt, svg

I would like to display a svg file inside a eclipse view.

a) It would be nice if the plugin can do basic animations too (coloring the area on mouse over).

I look for a more practical information: what plugin or library has somebody successfully used?

b) or a variant to use svg together with swt.

Btw. have already googled for "eclipse svg plugin" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Look at: eclipse GMF: http://www.mail-archive.com/batik-users@xmlgraphics.apache.org/msg02782.html they use:
org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt.internal.graphics.Graphics2DToGraphicsAdaptor
and sources are in
org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt.internal.svg.
SWTImageTranscoder

b) http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.gui/2006-04/msg00317.html

c) try https://svgsalamander.dev.java.net/

Comment: Have you evaluated or used these?  What can you tell us about them?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

do you know this one:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgplugin/

google for "eclipse svg plugin" brings up some more.

Comment: Yes this one I know, is rather old.